# mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt,

Tags: php, html, mysql, parameters, boolean

Hi I am in need of some help. I am currently trying to create a search page in which a user is able to search for a specific book by the Title of the book, the category, year and publisher

I have created my basic HTML search form and this is the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id ="SearchPage" action="SearchPage.php" method="get">
<h1> Search Page</h1>

    Book Title <input type="text" name="bookTitle" />

    Category <select name="catDesc">
                <option value = "Business & Commerce">Business & Commerce</option>
                <option value = "Databases">Databases</option>
                <option value = "Databases and Web Development">Databases and Web Development</option>
                <option value = "Fiction">Fiction</option>
                <option value = "Flex & Flash Programming">Flex & Flash Programming</option>
                <option value = "Netorks">Netorks</option>
                <option value = "Programming">Programming</option>
                <option value = "Systems Design">Systems Design</option>
                <option value = "Web Development">Web Development</option>
            </select>



    Publisher <input type="text" name="pubName"/>

    Year <input type="text" name="bookYear"/>

    <input type ="submit" value-"Find Books"/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the php code i have done below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <title>Search Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
     <tr>
     <th>Book Title</th>
     <th>Year</th>
     <th>Category</th>
     <th>Publisher</th>
     </tr>
<?php

include 'database_mysqli_conn.php';

$bookTitle = $_REQUEST['bookTitle'];
$bookYear =$_REQUEST['bookYear'];
$catDesc =$_REQUEST['catDesc'];
$pubName =$_REQUEST['pubName'];

$sql = "SELECT bookTitle, bookYear, catDesc, pubName, FROM nbc_book b inner join nbc_category c on b.catID = c.catID inner join nbc_publisher p on b.pubID = p.pubID WHERE 1";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $bookTitle, $bookYear, $bookPrice, $catDesc);

if (!empty($bookTitle)) {

    $sql= $sql." AND bookTitle = '$bookTitle'";

    }

if (!empty($bookYear)) {

    $sql= $sql." AND bookYear = '$bookYear'";

}

if (!empty($catDesc)) {

    $sql= $sql." AND catDesc = '$catDesc'";

}

if (!empty($pubName)) {

    $sql= $sql." AND pubName = '$pubName'";

}

while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
    echo "<tr>
                <td>$bookTitle</td>
                <td>$bookYear</td>
                <td>$catDesc</td>
                <td>$pubName</td>
             </tr>";
}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
mysqli_close($conn);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

the problem is, this is the error message i receive when i submit the search:

Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /home/unn_w11036829/public_html/PHPexercises/SearchPage.php on line 27

Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /home/unn_w11036829/public_html/PHPexercises/SearchPage.php on line 28

Warning: mysqli_stmt_fetch() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /home/unn_w11036829/public_html/PHPexercises/SearchPage.php on line 54

Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /home/unn_w11036829/public_html/PHPexercises/SearchPage.php on line 63
Book Title  Year    Category    Publisher

Can anyone please tell me where i am going wrong! I have been stuck on this for the past hour and its driving me insane.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You have a comma before FROM in your query.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). It's worth noting that PDO and named placeholders makes this kind of conditional composition a lot easier.

Comment: oh dear silly me. its always the smallest thing :( Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query prepare failed, you failed to check for failure, etc...

```
$sql = "SELECT bookTitle, bookYear, catDesc, pubName, FROM nbc_book b inner join ..."
                                                    ^--- stray comma
```

Never **EVER** assume a db query will succeed. Especially while developing. Always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

CHANGE

```
$sql = "SELECT bookTitle, bookYear, catDesc, pubName, FROM nbc_book b inner join nbc_category c on b.catID = c.catID inner join nbc_publisher p on b.pubID = p.pubID WHERE 1";
```

TO

```
$sql = "SELECT bookTitle, bookYear, catDesc, pubName FROM nbc_book b inner join nbc_category c on b.catID = c.catID inner join nbc_publisher p on b.pubID = p.pubID WHERE 1";
```

Notice the comma after your pubName.

EDIT: You should be wrapping your mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) In an if to make sure you are catching errors like so

```
if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
 //YOUR CODE
}
else{
echo mysqli_stmt_error;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am now experiencing another problem and when i try to submit my search result it is bringing up all of the data from my sql table and not just what i was searching for, any ideas why ?